# Yii Cactiveform get url

Tags: yii

I am struggling with Cactiveform in Yii using get method. This is my code:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'inlineForm',
    'type'=>'inline',
  'method'=>'get',
  'action'=> array('searchview'),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'well'),
)); 
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'year',$arrYears); 
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'month',$mons); 
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'day',$days); 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'submit', 'type'=>'primary','label'=>'Vyhledat')); 
  $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

When I click the submit button I get this URL:

```
http://stavbadomusvepomoci.cz/stavba_naklady/index.php?r=expenses%2Fsearchview&Expenses%5Byear%5D=2013&Expenses%5Bmonth%5D=0&Expenses%5Bday%5D=0&yt0=
```

The problem is that the name of the fields is Expenses[year] insted of just: year. When I delete it, this url works just fine.

```
http://stavbadomusvepomoci.cz/stavba_naklady/index.php?r=expenses%2Fsearchview&year=2013&month=0&day=0&yt0=
```

And my search returns 400 error because it does not recognize the url. I have this working using reguler CHtml::beginForm, but I am hoping this could be working with CActive form.

So my question is: How can I get rid of the Expenses[] in the url so cactiveform works.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using $_GET["Expenses"] instead of the whole $_GET array on the server side, since it might contain non-search related variables like the CSRF token.

The only way I see achieving what you want is the htmlOptions parameter of the dropDownListRow. You could give it a specific name which leads to yii not setting a model-attribute dependant name.

```
$form->dropDownListRow($model, 'year', $arrYears, array("name" => "year"));
```

Comment: amazing! adding the specific name did the trick. Had no idea I could do that! I am learning new stuff with Yii everyday. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Vojtech No problem, you can usually give the htmlOptions array (which appears in various places in Yii, as you can see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/search/?q=htmloptions&type=api-suggest)) any key-value pair which should appear in the tag itself. Usually you shouldn't overuse and especially think about creating your own CHtml subclass to define your own element types.